# Using $compile and isolated scope together in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why can't I use isolated scope and $compile together in my case? When I use the isolated scope, I can't $compile and append the element.

```
app.directive('btnClick', function($compile) {

  return {
    scope: {
      btnCheck : '@'
    },
    restrict: 'A',

    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var el = $compile(scope.$eval(attrs.actionBtn))(scope);
      element.append(el);

    }

  }

})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/6mlTuhqJz9bzUkF4lNrY?p=preview

Please help

Comment: I did not check your plunker, but what if you do `scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.actionBtn)`

Comment: Sorry http://plnkr.co/edit/6mlTuhqJz9bzUkF4lNrY?p=preview

Comment: And when use $parent, ng-click is not workin on appended items

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using the template or templateUrl property in the directive?

Comment: Your variable isn't on the scope, it's on the controller "as" class.  scope.$eval is just giving you the string back.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<div btn-click action-btn="{{dctrl.clk}}"></div>`
and in your link function first create the element and after that use the $compile:

```
var el = angular.element(attrs.actionBtn);
el = $compile(el)(scope);
element.append(el);
```

I also can see that you want to pass a parameter string named **btnCheck** to the directive **btnClick** but you put the attribute on the wrong tag.
Don't know exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can make this reuseable.  You can bind the behaviors in a directive using '&'.  As you can see in the demo, both buttons are using the same directive and template, but each is bound to a different function in the controller:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('demoCtrl', function() {
  this.click = function() {
    alert('clicked');
  }
  this.otherclick = function() {
    alert('clicked other');
  }
})

app.directive('btnClick', function($compile) {
  return {
    scope: {
      name: '@btnClick',
      action: '&actionBtn'
    },
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<button ng-click="action()">{{name}}</button>',

  }

})
```

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}
button:hover, button:focus {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-color: #adadad;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="demoCtrl as dctrl">
    <div btn-click="Button 1" action-btn="dctrl.click()"></div>
    <div btn-click="Button 2" action-btn="dctrl.otherclick()"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```